# Shopify JavaScript Buy SDK can't console log collections[0].products on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, shopify-api

I'm trying to render the products in a collection with Shopify buy. The problem is that I am logging collections[5] in the console with no problem. I can then log collections[5].products and the console will then give me the graphmodel for the products in that collection. Then as soon as I refresh the page, I get the error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')

Code that works for the page:

```
const Home = () => {
  const { fetchAllProducts, fetchAllCollections, products, collections } = useContext(ShopContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllCollections();
  }, [fetchAllCollections]);

  console.log(collections[5]);`
```

Code that sends an error on refresh:

```
const Home = () => {
  const { fetchAllProducts, fetchAllCollections, products, collections } = useContext(ShopContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllCollections();
  }, [fetchAllCollections]);

  console.log(collections[5].products);
```

My shop context:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Client from "shopify-buy";

const ShopContext = React.createContext();

const client = Client.buildClient({
  domain: process.env.REACT_APP_SHOPIFY_DOMAIN,
  storefrontAccessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_SHOPIFY_API,
});

export class shopProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    collection: {},
    collections: [],
    product: {},
    products: [],
    checkout: {},
    isCartOpen: false,
    isMenuOpen: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.checkout_id) {
      this.fetchCheckout(localStorage.checkout_id);
    } else {
      this.createCheckout();
    }
  }

  createCheckout = async () => {
    const checkout = await client.checkout.create();
    localStorage.setItem("checkout_id", checkout.id);
    this.setState({ checkout: checkout });
  };

  fetchCheckout = (checkoutId) => {
    client.checkout.fetch(checkoutId).then((checkout) => {
      this.setState({ checkout: checkout });
    });
  };

  addItemToCheckout = async (variantId, quantity) => {
    const lineItemsToAdd = [{ variantId, quantity: parseInt(quantity, 10) }];
    const checkout = await client.checkout.addLineItems(
      this.state.checkout.id,
      lineItemsToAdd
    );
    this.setState({ checkout: checkout });
    this.openCart();
  };

  removeLineItem = async (lineItemIdsToRemove) => {
    const checkout = await client.checkout.removeLineItems(
      this.state.checkout.id,
      lineItemIdsToRemove
    );
    this.setState({ checkout: checkout });
  };

  fetchAllCollections = async () => {
    const collections = await client.collection.fetchAllWithProducts();
    this.setState({ collections: collections });
  }

  fetchAllProducts = async () => {
    const products = await client.product.fetchAll();
    this.setState({ products: products });
  };

  fetchProductWithHandle = async (handle) => {
    const product = await client.product.fetchByHandle(handle);
    this.setState({ product: product });
  };

  closeCart = () => {
    this.setState({ isCartOpen: false });
  };

  openCart = () => {
    this.setState({ isCartOpen: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ShopContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          fetchAllProducts: this.fetchAllProducts,
          fetchProductWithHandle: this.fetchProductWithHandle,
          addItemToCheckout: this.addItemToCheckout,
          removeLineItem: this.removeLineItem,
          closeCart: this.closeCart,
          openCart: this.openCart,
          closeMenu: this.closeMenu,
          openMenu: this.openMenu,
          fetchAllCollections: this.fetchAllCollections,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ShopContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const ShopConsumer = ShopContext.Consumer;

export { ShopConsumer, ShopContext };

export default shopProvider;
```

The docs for shopify buy:
https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/#fetching-collections

I've tried deleting fetchAllProducts and products from the page to no avail.

I've tried deleting fetchAllProducts and products thinking that having products and fetchAllProducts were redundant and therefore not fetching the correct variable called "products". This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing a project using the JS SDK but I'm using NextJS. I believe it's because collections is an array of objects and each object represents a single collection.

The products property is not a property of the array itself, but rather a property of each object in the array.

To get access to the products of each collection you can do the following:

```
const allCollectionProducts = collections.map(collection => collection.products);
```

**OR**

```
const firstCollection = collections[0];
const firstCollectionProducts = firstCollection.products;
```

Comment: It's still doing the same thing. I've assigned a variable to the collection I want to access and it works on hot refresh. However when I hard refresh the page, it does the same thing. Except now the console is returning the error "cannot read properties of undefined reading ('slice').